# Plugins main class not found when using Maven

Tags: java, maven, plugins, classnotfoundexception

So, I recently created my first ever plugin, called BetterTeaming. This plugin is using spigot api. After the plugin was released, after some time I was suggested to use Maven to  remove the spigot-api dependency from the compiled jar. This should have shrinked the file size. However I do not know much about Maven. I managed to set it up, and copied my files to the Maven folder (Hierarchy screenshot included), but everytime I load the plugin on my local server Minecraft it throws ClassNotFoundException at me, and stops the plugin from loading.

What exactly is incorrect?

So, I recently created my first ever plugin, called BetterTeaming. This plugin is using spigot api. After the plugin was released, after some time I was suggested to use Maven to  remove the spigot-api dependency from the compiled jar. This should have shrinked the file size. However I do not know much about Maven. I managed to set it up, and copied my files to the Maven folder (Hierarchy screenshot included), but everytime I load the plugin on my local server (Minecraft) it throws `ClassNotFoundException` at me, and stops the plugin from loading.

Hierarchy

Package with the main class src - main - plugin-package
Plugin.yml src - main - resources - plugin.yml

Error message

```
[22:20:52 ERROR]: Could not load 'plugins\BT-maven-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar' in folder 'plugins'
org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidPluginException: Cannot find main class `plugin.Main'
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.<init>(PluginClassLoader.java:80) ~[spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.loadPlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:129) ~[spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:327) ~[spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:248) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_12_R1.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:305) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_12_R1.CraftServer.reload(CraftServer.java:750) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
        at org.bukkit.Bukkit.reload(Bukkit.java:525) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
        at org.bukkit.command.defaults.ReloadCommand.execute(ReloadCommand.java:27) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
        at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:141) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_12_R1.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:648) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_12_R1.CraftServer.dispatchServerCommand(CraftServer.java:634) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.DedicatedServer.aP(DedicatedServer.java:444) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.DedicatedServer.D(DedicatedServer.java:407) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.C(MinecraftServer.java:679) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:577) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_301]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: plugin.Main
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:152) ~[spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:100) ~[spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_301]
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.<init>(PluginClassLoader.java:78) ~[spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
        ... 15 more
```

What exactly is incorrect?

I must say, that the ordinary version of the plugin, with no Maven used, works fine.
I must say, that the ordinary version of the plugin, with no Maven used, works fine.

Comment: There is no `plugin.yml`. The question is why you have a yml file ? Second how does your pom.xml setup look like?

Answer (score 0):

The `main` entry in your `plugin.yml` file contains `plugin.Main`, but it appears that there is no `plugin.Main` class in your jar file. Since you haven't included your `pom.xml`, I cannot know what exactly is going wrong. I recommend you to look at [these maven plugin setups](https://github.com/Pieter12345/JavaLoader/blob/9922716f08a08cb0122625f037309b15ba145cc9/pom.xml#L28-L58) and see whether changing your setup to use these plugins works.